# How to implement generic function for adding both numbers and String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am trying to write a generic function which will add strings, integer, floats, doubles.

But my generic function is working with number only when my generic is Numeric constraint.

```
func add<T: Numeric>(first:T, second:T) -> T {
    return first + second
}
```

To work with string, it has to be sequence but again it will not work with numbers.

So, please let me know what wrong I am doing here.
Is there any way to make single function for adding strings and numbers.

Comment: And by adding strings you mean "ab" + "c" = "abc"?

Comment: You can create 3 same constraints with different constraint ```add<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>```, ```add<T: Numeric>``` and  simple string parameter

Comment: @RajaKishan much easier to use the already existing `AdditiveArithmetic` protocol but not sure how OP would subtract a String

Comment: @LeoDabus yeah, I wish they had separated out the '+' operator; there's quite a few types for which you can define a sensible addition operation but not a subtraction one.

Comment: In what way is "add strings" meaningfully similar to "add integers?" If `"dog" + "cat" == "dogcat"`, does that  mean that `1 + 1 == 11`? Or do you mean "add strings if and only if they can be converted to decimal-number-like things, and then convert hem back to a formatted decimal string after computing." If that's what you mean, it has no relationship to "add numbers" since one has failure cases and the other has completely different failure cases. To help us answer this question, it would be helpful to show what the calling code would look like, and what results you're expecting.

Comment: @RobNapier Gosh, that's a great point. I just assumed that the OP meant using the existing `+` operator... but from your comment I see that that may have been a faulty assumption.

Comment: @idz Yeah; your answer definitely answers to what the question asks (and I'm happy to upvote it because of that), but it's also the canonical case for why there's no protocol that says "this has a trivial `init()`." Saying something is "plusable" doesn't tell you anything about semantics, and protocols are all about semantics (i.e. *meaning*). https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/

Comment: @RobNapier That article is a great read. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution is this. You know you want your method to be applicable to anything that has a `+` defined... So define an explicit protocol. Let's call it `Addable`:

```swift
protocol Addable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
```

Now, using extensions, declare conformance to `Addable` for the types you care about:

```swift
extension String: Addable {}
extension Int: Addable {}
extension Double: Addable {}
```

And define your `add` function as:

```swift
func  add<T: Addable>(first: T, second: T) -> T {
    return first + second
}
```

Comment: So for float, CGFloat and others, I have to conform them with Addable protocol, right? Then what is wrong in approach if i typecast generic type (T) to String, number like Int, Double etc and it will return sum. Otherwise in other cases, my return type would be optional, so I will return nil.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what exactly you're trying to do. The question seemed like you were looking for a way to apply the `+` operator to various types and the answer shows how you _can_ do this, but avoids the question of whether you _should_. What do you expect add("12", "3") to return? If you use the inbuilt `+` it will be "123" did you intend it to return "15"? If you want "15" what should the answer be for add("ab", "c") be? You mentioned nil in your comment, but there is no mention of optionals in the question. Perhaps clarify the question some more.

Comment: yeah, thanks for above approach. I am just telling other approach, nothing more than that. Thanks again for the help

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it was useful. As I said in the comment, if you have the time to clarify what you're trying to do, there may be a better approach. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Is there any other optimize way to achieve the solution because if we need to pass any other data type like float then again we need to use an extension to declare conformance for this type, So I want don't want this ?@idz

Comment: @RahulSharma If you add a new protocol, as this solution does, there is no way for the compiler to know that an existing type conforms to that protocol unless you explicitly tell it.

Comment: can u write the code snippet here?

Comment: The second code snippet in the answer demonstrates this. You use extensions. I know you said you don't want to do that, but then the compiler has no way of knowing that the existing types conform to the protocol.